# How to Write a blog post with slug & image (django)

Tags: python, django

When I clicked the publish button. I get this error (image field = `This field is required), and it's not submitting the post.

[image]

**`models.py:`**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Put a Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=264, unique=True, null=True)
    blog_content = models.TextField(verbose_name='What is on your mind')
    blog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', verbose_name='Image', null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

**`views.py:`**

```
@login_required
def createblog(request):
    form = CreateBlogPost()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPost(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            blog_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            blog_obj.author = request.user
            title = blog_obj.blog_title
            print(title)
            blog_obj.slug = title.replace(" ", "-")+"-"+str(uuid.uuid4())
            print(blog_obj.slug)
            blog_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render(request, 'App_Blog/create_blog.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`This field is required` this is a `Validation` error from `Django` form and it depends on your `models`, if you are using model form you have to set `blank=True` like this

```
blog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', verbose_name='Image', null=True,blank=True)
```

`blank=True` means field can be empty (it is not required field) and `null=True` means your database table `column` can accept `null`  values.

Comment: I set the model attribute as you suggest to me. but I can't upload an image with a blog post in my database table.
updated all column but not the image column

Comment: Did you added image  field in your `forms.py` and don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

Comment: Thanks a million :D

I forget to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form tag